# Race condition for "Remember Me" cookies

Tags: algorithm, authentication, cookies, session-cookies, remember-me

I'm building a SPA (single page application) and I have multiple parallel javascript requests to my server.

I'm also using the amazing https://github.com/volatiletech/authboss and it's **Remember me** module which I think has an "issue": is not a bug, is not a problem, is a missing feature!

#### DESCRIPTION

Let's say I have a `rm` (remember me) cookie saved in my browser along with the session one.

If the session cookie expires and my SPA sends multiple requests to my server with `rm` cookie only the first one is correctly authenticated.

The second one (and so on) can't find anymore it's token in the storer (deleted before in the first request flow).

#### ALGORITHM

I'm using the same algorithm you can find in `authboss-sample`: https://github.com/volatiletech/authboss-sample/blob/master/storer.go#L333-L352.

#### RELATED QUESTIONS

- [Race Condition for Persistent "Remember Me" Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948918/race-condition-for-persistent-remember-me-cookies)
- [How to combine a persistent login cookie with parallel AJAX requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613526/how-to-combine-a-persistent-login-cookie-with-parallel-ajax-requests)
- [How to fix "Invalid remember-me token (Series/token) mismatch" Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17425275/how-to-fix-invalid-remember-me-token-series-token-mismatch-error)
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/28314
- [Remember-me fails when two or more requests come at the same time. (without Spring Security)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44237177/remember-me-fails-when-two-or-more-requests-come-at-the-same-time-without-spri)

#### QUESTION

As you can see this is not strictly a problem with authboss.

What can we suggest to the world?

Can we solve it somehow?

Comment: When does this `rm` cookie expire?

Comment: Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948918/race-condition-for-persistent-remember-me-cookies. Remember me tokens need to be deleted after each use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Race Condition for Persistent "Remember Me" Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948918/race-condition-for-persistent-remember-me-cookies)